# Lifting robot that moves like a plotter

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm

I'm looking for what a robot that moves like a plotter but can grab a load up to 1kg with a claw, lift, rotate and place in another location within its range.  What is this type of robot called?

[image]

Comment: XY gantry robot

Comment: @jsotola Good answer.  Why not make it a "real" answer next time?

Answer (score 2):

Cartesian robots have the characteristic that their axes move in Cartesian (x-y-z) directions.

Answer (score 0):

The picture is of a Gantry robot, but for your workcase you can use manipulator like [ABB pick and place](https://www.robots.com/robots/abb-irb-340sa) robot for more dexterity.

Comment: Aren't gantry robots just normal robots suspended on en external linear axis?

Comment: 1kg is a lot for these delta robots (especially if add the weight of the gripper to the weight of the object) and they have very limited workspaces. As OP did not give a lot of information the task, proposing this robot is just a guess.